# How do I make a citation table where work can't refer to itself?

Tags: database-design, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE Work(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title CHAR(20),
    date DATETIME,
    description VARCHAR(1000),
    CONSTRAINT Work_PK PRIMARY KEY (id),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- In the following, do we have to worry about work_1 being = to work_2, how can we prevent this ? 

CREATE TABLE Work_Citation(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                       work_1 INT NOT NULL,
                       work_2 INT NOT NULL,
                       CONSTRAINT Work_Citation_PK_1 PRIMARY KEY (id),
                       CONSTRAINT Work_Citation_PK_2 UNIQUE (work_1,work_2),
                       CONSTRAINT Work_Citation_FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (work_1) REFERENCES Work(id),
                       CONSTRAINT Work_Citation_FK_2 FOREIGN KEY (work_2) REFERENCES Work(id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT  CHARSET=utf8;

-- A second query, can I do without the id column in Work_Citation? Any comments on when we should / should not use it?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can use check constraint, add this to table definition:

```
CONSTRAINT check_work_ids_are_not_equal CHECK work_1 <> work_2
```

2. yes, you can create PK on (work_1, work_2)
3. it has a sense to add index on Work_citation(work_2). This way you will not need to scan the whole Work_Citation table when delete rows from Work table to check that the are no referencing rows

Comment: When do we use id and when do we use PK on (work_1,work_2) ? Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2338823 usually we use id when we need to reference to this id from other tables and when there are no other good candidates for primary key. Please see this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337503/whats-the-best-practice-for-primary-keys-in-tables

Comment: `CHECK`is available in MariaDB 10.2 and MySQL 8.0.19.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for useful comment. MySQL should support check constraint starting from 8.0.16 (but I didn't test it with this version). MariaDB - from 10.2.1. For older versions we can implement a solution using triggers but QA didn't comment this part of my answer and MariaDB 10.2 is more than 4 years old now.

Comment: (8.0.19 fixed some big bugs in that area.)  Some features are shipped much sooner in MariaDB; some are much sooner in MySQL.  Yes, Triggers are a possible fallback.

Comment: I brought up the version numbers for the sake of others reading this Q&A.  Not all of them have a new enough version.

Comment: I have another query. In the Work_Citation table, if one piece of Work say work_1 = 1 cites another piece of Work say work_2 = 2, then work_1 = 2 cannot cite work_2 = 1, ie the converse is not possible. How would I check for this ?

Comment: @user2338823 This question completely differs from your original one. Please modify the question and describe what exactly do you need to check and what version of database server do you use. What if you have such sequence, for example: (work_1 = 1, work_2 = 2), (work_1 = 2, work_2 = 3), (work_1 = 3, work_2 = 1)?

Comment: @Nikita, apologies. I have posted a follow up query [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270901/how-to-prevent-a-circular-citation)