# How to prevent a circular citation?

Tags: database-design, mariadb

This is a follow up query of [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270860/how-do-i-make-a-citation-table-where-work-cant-refer-to-itself/270861?noredirect=1#comment533249_270861)

I am using : mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.44-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

```
CREATE TABLE Work(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title CHAR(20),
    date DATETIME,
    description VARCHAR(1000),
    CONSTRAINT Work_PK PRIMARY KEY (id),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE Work_Citation(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                   work_1 INT NOT NULL,
                   work_2 INT NOT NULL,
                   CONSTRAINT Work_Citation_PK_1 PRIMARY KEY (id),
                   CONSTRAINT Work_Citation_PK_2 UNIQUE (work_1,work_2),
                   CONSTRAINT Work_Citation_FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (work_1) REFERENCES Work(id),
                   CONSTRAINT Work_Citation_FK_2 FOREIGN KEY (work_2) REFERENCES Work(id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT  CHARSET=utf8;

-- How to prevent circular citation?
-- Example 1: In the Work_Citation table, if one piece of Work say work_1 = 1 cites another piece of Work say work_2 = 2, then work_1 = 2 cannot cite work_2 = 1, ie the converse is not possible.
-- Example 2 : (work_1 = 1, work_2 = 2), (work_1 = 2, work_2 = 3), (work_1 = 3, work_2 = 1)?
```

Comment: maybe it's time to upgrade your server version and use recursive common table expressions? ) please check answers to this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739150/to-find-infinite-recursive-loop-in-cte Otherwise you will need to use solution based on while loop + temporary tables

Comment: Add `CONSTRAINT (work_1 < work_2)` and swap them before insert if necessary.